# Styling list items in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, list, drop-down-menu

Hi I am having a very strange experiencing with list item navigation menu.

On the main parent `li` I have a background color, but when I drop down in to the `li ul li` I want the background color to be removed, which on all browsers except `IE9/8/7` works fine.

My Basic code is:

```
 .topnav li {
    background:#c60;
    }
    .topnav li ul li {
    background:none;
    }
```

in `IE` is still displays the `background color`, i have tried everything I can think of.

the website is [***link is***](http://www.arcdatasystems.co.uk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `li`s have a gradient filter applied to them in Internet Explorer - you'll need to set this to none (or equivalent) to remove the background.

E.g.

```
.topnav li ul li { filter: none; }
```